# Erro ao usar a função Sanitize

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao usar essa função Sanitize, já fiz as verificações e não consegui encontrar onde está o erro, estou passando esses valores para a função:

```
    $data1 = Sanitize::filter($_POST['data1']); 
    $data2 = Sanitize::filter($_POST['data2']); 
    $titulo = Sanitize::filter($_POST['titulo']);   
    $descricao = Sanitize::filter($_POST['descricao']);
    $observacao = Sanitize::filter($_POST['observacao']);
    $vagas = Sanitize::filter($_POST['vagas']);
```

A função está assim:

```
abstract class Sanitize {
/**
 * Filter
 * 
 * @param  mixed $value
 * @param  array $modes
 * @return mixed
 * @static
 * @since  1.0
 */
    static public function filter($value, $modes = array('sql', 'html')) {
        if (!is_array($modes)) {
            $modes = array($modes);
        }
        if (is_string($value)) {
            foreach ($modes as $type) {
              $value = self::_doFilter($value, $type);
            }
            return $value;
        }
        foreach ($value as $key => $toSanatize) {
            if (is_array($toSanatize)) {
                $value[$key]= self::filter($toSanatize, $modes);
            } else {
                foreach ($modes as $type) {
                  $value[$key] = self::_doFilter($toSanatize, $type);
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }
/**
 * DoFilter
 * 
 * @param  mixed $value
 * @param  array $modes
 * @return mixed
 * @static
 * @since  1.0
 */
    static protected function _doFilter($value, $mode) {
        switch ($mode) {
            case 'html':
                $value = strip_tags($value);
                $value = addslashes($value);
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
                break;

            case 'sql':
                $value = preg_replace(sql_regcase('/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*| |\\\\)/'),'',$value);
                $value = trim($value);
                break;
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

E estou recebendo esse erro:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cpcocari/public_html/sanitize.class.php on line 48

O erro está sendo acusado nessa linha:

> foreach ($value as $key => $toSanatize) {

Comment: Onde fica a linha 48 no seu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dados que você está passando são arrays? O foreach funciona apenas com arrays. Você deve verificar se a variável de entrada é um array para executar o foreach.

```
static public function filter($value, $modes = array('sql', 'html')) {
        if (!is_array($modes)) {
            $modes = array($modes);
        }
        if (is_string($value)) {
            foreach ($modes as $type) {
              $value = self::_doFilter($value, $type);
            }
            return $value;
        }
        if(is_array($values)){
            foreach ($value as $key => $toSanatize) {
                if (is_array($toSanatize)) {
                    $value[$key]= self::filter($toSanatize, $modes);
                } else {
                    foreach ($modes as $type) {
                       $value[$key] = self::_doFilter($toSanatize,           $type);
                }
            }
        }
}
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Os valores passados estão no topo da pergunta @Leandro Araujo, são arrays, valeu pela sugestão.